# Please how do I make this function Tail-recursive in F#?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data, f#-3.0

let ListtoTuple (lst:'a list) :('a * 'a) list =

```
let rec loop (lt :'a list) acc =
    match lt with         
    | x:: y :: t-> (x,y):: loop  t acc 
    |   _   -> acc
loop lst []
```

Question: ListtoTuple 6 [1..1000000]

I want this kind of result : [(1, 2); (3, 4); (5, 6); (7, 8); (9, 10)...] but I keep getting process is terminated due to StackOverflow. Please, I would like to know if there is anything I am doing wrong.

Comment: Don't use unrelated tags. It doesn't improve visibility, it only annoys people interested in those tags. As for `tail-recursive` it means the recursive call comes *last*.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost correct. The problem is here:

```
(x,y):: loop f t acc
```

You are concatenating to the result of `loop` which means it is not tail recursive because it has to wait for the result of `loop` to then concatenate.

The key is in the parameter `acc` which stands for accumulator. That means that is where you need to be concatenating your resulting list, which then gets passed to the next level until there is nothing more to add and then the `acc` has the completed list which is returned here:

```
|   _   -> acc
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207395/f-integers-to-pair-of-integers/53208275#53208275):

```
let listToPairList lst =
    let rec aux acc lst = 
        match lst with
        | []         -> acc |> List.rev
        | x::[]      -> (x,x)::acc |> List.rev
        | x1::x2::xs -> aux ((x1,x2)::acc) xs
    aux [] lst
```